# pandas str.contains in pyspark dataframe in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Please suggest how can i achieve string contains on a column in spark dataframe,
In pandas i used to do

```
df1 = df[df['col1'].str.contains('anystring_to_match')]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
df['col1'].like('%anystring_to_match%')
```

Comment: df[df['col1'].like('%anystring_to_match%')] works. Thanks.

Comment: It's an exact match, does not work the same as .str.contains

Comment: @Max: in what specific respect is it different from `str.contains`? Seems to me like the semantics should be identical.